# Are there standards / best practices for icon images? ie, "Delete", "Refresh", etc

Tags: user-interface, usability

Some icons are pretty much universally recognized by now. Examples that come to mind are a ? for help, trash can for delete, x for close, or magnifying glass for search.

Many of these are microsoft icons that are just so widely recognized that they can be used elsewhere for specific actions without explanation (or copyright infringement).

Currently I am looking for an icon whose meaning would be "change this".  I could use a(delta) triangle, but I think that would be confusing, as it is often used for more info or expand this.

I can also design a new icon ...

But is there a standards for icon images? Or a least, a best practices? If so, can you provide me a link or the name of a book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) and [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/ue/) have UX design guidelines that detail such things and much more.

Answer (score 0):

"change this" AKA "modify" normally is some notepad with a pencil on it

"refresh" would be a circular arrow or some "back and forth"-arrow

Comment: Re notepad and pencil: that connotes edit, and I am looking for change as in pick "totally new" from another ui presentaion (different page, or popup window). Re refresh: that usually connotes "update the info on this page" rather than change the selection.

Comment: @Lill Lansey: ah, ok, obviously I wasn't aware of or misunderstood the context in which you want to use the icons. However, this underlines how important it is to look for yourself whether or not an icon expresses what the functionality behind it does.